# System.Xml.XmlException error upon using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I can't understand where problem is, despite the fact, that this code pretty easy.

I have such function:

```
public void WriteToDoc(string path)    
        {
             XDocument doc = new XDocument (new XElement("General parameters",
                                                    new XElement("num_path", num_path.Text),
                                                    new XElement("Gen_Peroid", Gen_Peroid.Text),
                                                    new XElement("Alg_Perioad", Alg_Perioad.Text)
                                                         )
                                          );
            doc.Save(path);
        }
```

`num_path.Text`, `Gen_Peroid.Text` and `Alg_Perioad.Text` are `string`.

This is how I use this function:

```
File.Create(@"C:\ProgramData\RadiolocationQ\Q.xml");
WriteToDoc(@"C:\ProgramData\RadiolocationQ\Q.xml");
```

Comment: What's the rest of the exception text?

Comment: `System.Xml.XmlException`error upon calling `WriteToDoc` function.

Comment: Right, but what's the actual exception text? Not the exception type? What's the `Message` of the exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xml Elements cannot contain spaces. Fix your XML to conform to the standard

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp

Comment: @Rocketq, please make sure to up vote and accept this as the answer. Good luck!